# Android Studio emulator and AMD CPU

Tags: android-studio, amd-processor, haxm

I can't run my app on standard Nexus 5 emulator. It seems it requires Intel HAXM but i have an AMD processor. So how can i use the emulator without buying an Intel processor (or installing Linux)?

Comment: This is now possible. See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57917310/676571

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have an AMD processor, you can download an ARM image, but it is super slow on x86 platforms.

The x86 image does not work with AMD CPUs, because the x86 image needs HAXM installed which needs VT-X support, and only Intel CPUs support it.

So you can download the Genymotion emulator, which supports both VT-X & AMD-V technology.

Comment: In fact, i have x64 platform but i don't think it plays role or does it?

Comment: is you x64 platform Intel or AMD?  Genymotion works good at Intel and AMD platform.

Comment: it works at AMD cpu in 64 bit mode， my desktop in office is AMD，and use Win7 64bit + JDK 64bit+ Andriod Studio+ Genymotion, it works very well.

Answer (score 4):

Genymotion is super fast. Other than hooking your physical device up to test, it's the next best thing. Android Studio emulator is not efficient for testing. I am using the personal version of Genymotion.

Answer (score 3):

With the latest API 30, even x86 emulators are very fast in AMD processors. For this in Windows, you follow this below.

You absolutely don't need Intel HAXM (Hardware Accelerated Execution Mode) in AMD processors, because they are AMD processors.

Just enable (check) Windows Hypervisor Platform in Windows features as shown below.
[image]

Now, you can start emulators. No need of Intel HAXM.

Here is official link: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html

Answer (score 1):

You can run the ARM (non Intel) emulator image. From your list, just choose a non Intel emulation.

Comment: Where is this list to run the ARM emulator? I can't find it @codecats

Answer (score 1):

You should give [ARC Welder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-welder/emfinbmielocnlhgmfkkmkngdoccbadn) a try if all you just want to do is test an app, without all the distractions from an emulator. It works with the [Google App Runtime For Chrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Runtime_for_Chrome)

You simply feed it your app's apk file and it generates a folder containing your app's resources then it launches the app. Its still in heavy development, so not all apps work yet, but its really worth giving a try.

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me in 2024 for running AVD(Android Virtual Device) with AMD chipset like Ryzen.

OS: Windows 10
Chipset: Ryzen 7

Make sure you have enabled `Virtualization support` for your AMD CPU (`SVM` is `enabled` in BIOS), then follow the steps below.

NOTE: WSL won't work if you follow these steps.

Steps:

1. In search box type "gpedit" then Goto -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Device Guard -> Turn on Virtualization Based Security. Now Double click that and "Disable". Apply and Save.
2. In search box, type Turn Windows features on or off, now uncheck Hyper-V and restart system.
3. Open Registry Editor by typing regedit in search box, now Go to HKEYLOCALMACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceGuard. If it doesn't exist, add a new DWORD value named EnableVirtualizationBasedSecurity and set it to 0 to disable it (I already had it).
4. Next Go to HKEYLOCALMACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA. If it doesn't exis, add a new DWORD value named LsaCfgFlags and set it to 0 to disable it. (Also had it)
5. Open command prompt (not powershell) as a administrator and type the following commands:

```
bcdedit /create {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} /d "DebugTool" /application osloader
bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} path "\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\SecConfig.efi"
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} bootsequence {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215}
bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} loadoptions DISABLE-LSA-ISO,DISABLE-VBS
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

`Restart your windows` and now it should work when you run `silent_install.bat`, you can find it at `C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\SDK\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver`, if its not exist then ensure that you enable it at your `Android Studio > SDK Manage > SDK Tools > install 'Android Emulator hypervisor driver`