# I have AMD processor.when i run app in android studio it shows:

Tags: android-studio, amd-processor, haxm

> emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
>
> Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
>
> CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

after looking through some forum found suggestion about **genymotion**. but i want to use android studio emulator on AMD processor. appreciate if anyone would like to help.

Comment: Would that suggestion from a forum be [Android Studio emulator and AMD CPU](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28848283/1115360)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that you have installed Intel X 86 Emulator accelarator(Haxm Installer for Intel processors) or ARM system image(AMD).

Then go to the [SDK Folder path]\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager and run intelhaxm-android.exe.

If you get an error Virtualization technology is not enabled, enable Hardware Virtualization in BIOS setting:http://www.sysprobs.com/disable-enable-virtualization-technology-bios.

For AMD processors to use genymotion you need to have AMD-v enabled CPU.
Using Genymotion would be a better option

Comment: Peaked - you can't run haxm on a non Intel CPU. Title says has AMD.

Comment: @peaked..installed ARM system image(AMD) in android studio SDK manager. system is compatible with virtualization technology. but still shows the same error :)

Comment: Hardware acceleration absent for AMD in android studio.. Use Genymotion

Answer (score 0):

If you have an AMD processor, you can download the Genymotion emulator, which supports AMD-V technology.
You need to have **AMD-v** enabled

First, open the Android SDK Manager: **Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager**, then chose any package you want to download, expand it and select **ARM EABI v7a System** or **ARM 64 v8a** System Images and install.

Then, open Android AVD Manager: **Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager** and create an emulator.

You should restart Android Studio for be shure it works