# Android Emulator Error Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator, amd-processor

I have an AMD Quad-Core A6-6310 Processor with an AMD Radeon R4 Graphics and when I try to run the Android emulator in Eclipse or in the Android Studio I get the following error:

"Starting emulator for AVD 'Nexus_5_API_23_x86'
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!"

Any suggestions of a way around??

Comment: Use the ARM image or genymotion emulator. See 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27765457/android-studio-emulator-and-amd-cpu

Comment: @headuck brilliant I'll give them a shot :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have HAXM installer on your SDK Manager.

Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd)