# Appcompat error on eclipse

Tags: android

appcompat_v7

```
G:\programming\not\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:146: error: 
Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
```

Comment: There is not enough detail here to help, and why are you using Eclipse?

Comment: can't run apps in emulator above error is showing..   my processor is not compatible with android studio that's why i'm using eclipse ...

Comment: Your processor has no effect on the application itself. The emulator is what matters. Eclipse also has the same problem

Comment: For reference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27765457/android-studio-emulator-and-amd-cpu