# virtualization enable but can't install HAXM android studio

Tags: android-studio, intel, haxm, amd-processor

I enabled virtualization on AMD bios and disabled hyper-v but still can't install intel x86 emulator accelerator (haxm installer). Any help?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please refer to this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53676171/975887 Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

My laptop used to has this problem too (HP elitebook 8560p), you should go to BIOS and check if there are 2 virtualization technology enabled, disable 1, i dont remember what is it name, tell me if it works or not

Answer (score 0):

GO to Tools -> SDK manager -> Android SDK
[click here to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TN1jE.png)

- uncheck "hide obsolete package" than you can able to see the Intel x86 emulator accelerator
- then select "Intel x86 emulator accelerator (haxm installer)"
- And click on "Apply" to install the Intel x86 emulator accelerator

**To fix VT-x is disable/enable  issue**

- open run window+R
- Type msinfo32
- click "ok"
- search for the field "virtualization technology"

*To enable virtualization technology*

- go to restart but do not click the restart
- press and hold the "sift key" than click on restart
- choose option "troubleshoot" ->advance options -> UEFI firmware settings
- click on restart
- start BIOS settings
- go to advanced virtualization technology
- than go to "exit" tab and save the changes
- than check the virtualization technology  is enabled or not
- than click on exit setup

[click here to reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vP71TkSh67M)

Comment: Link-only answers are not a good fit for Stack Overflow's Q&A rules.  We require answers to still be useful even if links die.  If you can summarize the key point that youtube video makes, that could make an acceptable answer.  Although this question is probably a duplicate of [Android Studio emulator and AMD CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27765457)